# Threads and Hibernate with Spring MVC

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I am currently working on a web application which is basically a portfolio site for different *vendors*.

I was working on a thread which copies the details of a *vendor* and puts it against a new *vendor*, pretty straightforward.

The thread is intended to work fine but when selecting a particular `Catalog` object (this catalog object contains a `Velocity` template), the execution stops and it goes nowhere. Invoking the thread once again just hangs the whole application.

Here is my code.

```
public class CopySiteThread extends Thread {

    public CopySiteThread(ComponentDTO componentDTO, long vendorid, int admin_id) {
        /**Application specific business logic not exposed **/
    }

    public void run() {

        /** Application based Business Logic Not Exposed **/

        //Copy Catalog first
        List<Catalog> catalog = catalogDAO.getCatalog(vendorid);
        System.out.println(catalog);
        List<Catalog> newCat = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> catIdMapList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        Iterator<Catalog> catIterator = catalog.iterator();

        while (catIterator.hasNext()) {

            Catalog cat = catIterator.next();
            System.out.println(cat);
            int catId = catalogDAO.addTemplate(admin_id, cat.getHtml(), cat.getName(), cat.getNickname(), cat.getTemplategroup(), vendor.getVendorid());            
            catIdMapList.put(cat.getName(), catId);

            cat = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the thread is invoked like this.

```
CopySiteThread thread = new CopySiteThread(componentDTO, baseVendor, admin_id);
thread.start();
```

After a certain number of iterations, it gets stuck on line `Catalog cat = catIterator.next();`

This issue is rather strange because I've developed many applications like this without any problem.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was in the `addCatalog` method in `CatalogDAO`

```
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer templateID = null;

    Date date = new Date();

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Catalog catalog = new Catalog();
        //Business Logic
        templateID = (Integer) session.save(catalog);
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rolback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return templateID;
```

Fixed by adding a `finally` clause and closing all sessions.

Comment: If you want to answer on your own question, please provide some solution example code snippet, not just a description of what you've done